# Does upper shriek pullback commute with derived pushforward.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, duality-theorems, derived-functors

Does upper shriek pullback along a closed immersion of complex varieties $i: Z\hookrightarrow X$ commute with derived pushforward from analytic topology to Zariski topology ($R\alpha_*$)? (You can assume we are applying these to the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Q}$ and we are working with quasi-projective varieties) if not how one can calculate $i^{!}R\alpha_*\mathbb{Q}_X$, I expect this to be $R\alpha_*\mathbb{Q}_Z[-2c]$ (where $c$ is the codimension of the closed immersion), but cannot figure out a proof.